# How to find top 5 most occurring names in column grouped by another column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find the top occuring names in a column for each group from another column. I am new to R and am struggling to understand how other solutions are achieving this (solutions I find seem to resolve either the first or second part of the above).

A sample of the dataset is as follows:

```
Australia City | International City | Port_Region | Airline           | Month_num
"Melbourne"    | "Kular Lumpar"     | "East Asia" | "Air Asia"        | 1 
"Melbourne"    | "Auckland"         | "Oceania"   | "Air New Zealand" | 1
"Melbourne"    | "Auckland"         | "Oceania"   | "Air New Zealand" | 1
"Melbourne"    | "Auckland"         | "Oceania"   | "Air New Zealand" | 2
```

I am trying to find the top occurring airlines per month for an Australia city and display in a jitter chart.

Where I am having issues is with grouping the flights by airline and finding the top airlines.

The current code I am trying is:

```
sort(table(airlineMelb$Airline),decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]
airlineMelbPop <- c("Air New Zealand", "Air Asia")
  
as.factor(airlineMelbPop) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Month_num, y=Port_Region, color=Airline)) +
  labs(title="Most popular airlines per month for Melbourne") +
  geom_jitter()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: I can get the below now. This seems to be on the right track, where it is showing, for example, 'Qantas Airways' has 248 occurrences during the 9th month.

```
> dt = as.data.table(airlineMelb)
> dt[, .(nobs = .N), by = .(Australian_City, Month_num, Airline)][order(-nobs)]
     Australian_City Month_num            Airline nobs
  1:       Melbourne         9     Qantas Airways  248
  2:       Melbourne        12     Qantas Airways  242
  3:       Melbourne         3     Qantas Airways  224
  4:       Melbourne         6     Qantas Airways  224
  5:       Melbourne         1     Qantas Airways  195
 ---                                                  
494:       Melbourne         1 SriLankan Airlines    2
495:       Melbourne         1     LATAM Airlines    2
496:       Melbourne         1     Scoot Tigerair    2
497:       Melbourne         1     Japan Airlines    2
498:       Melbourne         1         Air Canada    2
```

How can this be used with ggplot2 to graph the top 5 airlines for each month (the above is only showing 5 months?

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` you could do

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(airlineMelb)
dt_res = dt[, .(nobs = .N), by = .(city, month, airline)][order(-nobs)]
```

`.N` gives you the number of observations within the groups in `by`, giving you the number of observations per airline, per city, and per month in decreasing order.

Comment: Thanks, when I use ```library(data.table)```, it says that there is no package called 'data.table'

Comment: Then you have to install it: `install.packages("data.table")`

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid I forgot installing packages requires a string. The code works but seems to only return 5 months? Edit in question

Comment: See my update, you need to assign it to a new data.table. It prints the first and last five rows by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.table to get the counts and the choose 5 rows from the sorted count column

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(airlineMelb)
dt[,counts:=sort(.N,descending=T),by=c("Australia City","Month_num","Airline")]

dt_top_5=dt[,.SD[1:5],by=c("Australia City","Month_num","Airline")]
```

- The first groupby gets the count in each group and sorts in descending order
- The second groupby is used to extract the first 5 rows from each sorted group.
- Note, if a particular group has less than 5 rows, a row of NA will be added

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is returning an error ```Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  unused argument (descending = TRUE)```  removing this then returns 5 rows all from a single month

Comment: please replace, descending by decreasing.
Also, do arrange the groupby column names in the order in which you want. 
I guess, you'll be needing the order "city","airline","month"